# Get the value with Hive regular expression

Tags: regex, hive

I want to extract a regular expression match value in hive. Below is my table column data. The data is only for single column. Consider this column as the csv list of data.

table1:col1

```
1234|REQUIRED|VALUE|ABC|true
3991|NOT REQUIRED|VALUE|ABC|false,1234|REQUIRED|VALUE||true 
3214|NOT REQUIRED|VALUE|ABCD|true,1234|REQUIRED|VALUE|ABC|false,1234|NOT REQUIRED|||false
1254|NOT REQUIRED||UPC|true,1235|REQUIRED||ABC|true
```

I want 2nd value between pipes.

1. 1st value => 1234
2. 4th Value => ABC
3. 5th Value => true

My Query:

```
select regexp_extract(col1, '1234\|([^|]{0,})\|[^|]{0,}\|ABC\|true', 1) col from table1;
```

Expected output:

```
REQUIRED
REQUIRED
<NULL>(OR EMPTY)
REQUIRED
```

Current Query Output:

```
<NULL>
<NULL>
<NULL>
<NULL>
```

I don't know where the query when wrong. This is a hive regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the required answer. I had to escape my pipe twice.

```
select regexp_extract(col1, '1234\\|([^|]{0,})\\|[^|]{0,}\\|ABC\\|true', 1) col from table1;
```

Comment: I still need to wait for 2 hours to select my own answer.. Waiting for it.. :)